# IDE does not allow Git compare with unmodified. VS2019 C#

Tags: c#, git, configuration, visual-studio-2019

The IDE for MS Visual Studio 2019... when using a context click .. for Source Control .. Shows the context Menu including Source Control..

- Commit [normal active]
- View History [normal active]
- Compare with unmodified [dimmed inactive]//Failure

How can I correct his failure?

Once the file is committed I can compare previous versions. Getting closer to the goal.

I see a similar question here at SO from many years ago.  Other people have the same problem.  I continue to investigate.  I am trying to accommodate a reasonable update path.

The set of files has a ancient history.  The project is [many] years old. It does compile and run correctly.  This is the latest question in trying to get [git] working reasonably. At this point I prefer to use Git via the IDE. I will use command line if I am forced.

A Project was created today.  The old project was added in the goal of modernizing some detail of which I am not aware.  Source Control has been disconnected and reconnected.  I am willing to delete any git repository since the files are about to be modified and do not have any diff history other than new comments.

MS VS2019 Git is working correctly on very new projects.